# Make not seeing python files

Tags: makefile

So I have this code:

```
CELLMECH=../cellmech
ALL: \
     png/01.png \
     png/02.png \
     png/03.png \
     png/04.png \
     png/05.png \
     png/06.png \
     png/07.png \
     png/08.png \
     png/09.png \
     png/10.png pickles/cellMech.10.pickle.gz

include ${CELLMECH}/png.make

pickles/modLink.01.pickle.gz : stretched-plane.pickle.gz

    mkdir -p pickles
    ${CELLMECH}/modLink.py -i  $< -o $@ -c conf

pickles/cellMech.01.pickle.gz : pickles/modLink.01.pickle.gz
    ${CELLMECH}/cellMech.py -dt 0.001 -nmax 10000 -i $< -o $@  > /dev/null
.
.
.
```

This is a .make extension file that I exceute with: "make -f 10.make"

Then I get an error:

```
modLink.py -i  stretched-plane.pickle.gz -o pickles/modLink.01.pickle.gz -c conf
make: modLink.py: No such file or directory
make: *** [10.make:19: pickles/modLink.01.pickle.gz] Error 127
```

I have tried everything, direct path to files, changing names, remaking the files, nothing worked. The make program can find the files with .make extension, but no matter what I do, it somehow cannot see the .py extension files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't have shown us the output from the makefile you provided.  Your makefile recipe has `${CELLMECH}/modlink.py ...` but the output you show just says `modlink.py ...`.  It's impossible for that recipe to generate that output.  There must be something else going on here.  Please be sure you are cutting and pasting _exactly_ the makefile rule and output you get, not paraphrasing.

Comment: Afaik that part is correct, as if I just change the modLink.py to any other .make file it finds it. Also there is the "include ${CELLMECH}/png.make" part, which runs fine.

Comment: I'm saying textually, it's not possible.  The recipe says `${CELLMECH}/modlink.py` but the output you show is just `modlink.py`.  That can't happen.  Even if the variable `CELLMECH` is empty the invocation MUST be at _least_ `/modlink.py`.  There's no possible way that the `/` can be omitted.

Comment: I played around a little and now I get  ```make: ../cellmech/modLink.py: No such file or directory``` back. It can still find the png.make file, just not the .py extension ones.

Comment: I don't understand comments like: _It can still find the png.make file, just not the .py extension ones_  I fear it results from a fundamental confusion.  What is "it" in this statement?  You can't compare `png.make`, which is a makefile, with `.py` extension files, which are python scripts.  They are completely different.  If you type `../cellmech/modLink.py` at your shell prompt, don't you get the same error?  What's the output from `ls -l ../cellmech/modLink.py`  What's the first line of the `../cellmech/modlink.py` file say?

Comment: I am reffering to GNU make, which runs the make files. To answer your questions:```...\examples>ls -l ../cellmech/modLink.py```                                                       gives back: ```-rwx------+ 1 budai budai 6280 2017 ápr.  29 ../cellmech/modLink.py ``` and the first line is: ```#!/usr/bin/python  -u``` then importing librarys and just usual python stuff.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're logged in as user `budai` and that running this command from the command line works.  In that case i recommend you edit the recipe and add in information to show the path etc., such as `pwd; ls -l ${CELLMECH}/modlink.py` etc. to see what's going on.  You can also try using `/usr/bin/python -u ${CELLMECH}/modlink.py` in your recipe directly and see if that helps or gives any other information.

Comment: Thank you for your help, in the end simply typing ```python``` before those lines were the solution.

Comment: Maybe that means that the interpreter `/usr/bin/python` doesn't exist on your system.  In that case, the first line of your file using `#!/usr/bin/python` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some consultation I found a solution: inserting "python" before the files, so they are given to the python interpeter directly. So the code runs in this form:

```
.
.
.
pickles/modLink.01.pickle.gz : stretched-plane.pickle.gz
    mkdir -p pickles
    python ${CELLMECH}/modLink.py -i  $< -o $@ -c conf

pickles/cellMech.01.pickle.gz : pickles/modLink.01.pickle.gz
    python ${CELLMECH}/cellMech.py -dt 0.001 -nmax 10000 -i $< -o $@  > /dev/null
.
.
.
```